# Firebase functions fails to send some push notifications using async sendMulticast method

Tags: typescript, firebase, async-await, firebase-cloud-messaging

This one has had me stumped for days. There's a lot of code so I hope you can stick with me..

**I've compiled all the code you see below in to one place to make it easier:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-us7xwt

Ok lets get started!

I run a daily cron job to notify users when they have new music to check out which triggers a firebase function. To query for releases my website API returns an object array of users and the artists they follow that have music releasing today:

**The API call that is run once the firebase function is triggered**

```
axios.get(`${apiURL}...`).then((response) => {
    var users = response.data;
    if(users.length > 0) {
        createTopics(users)
    }
})
```

The data returned from this API call is formatted like so and stored in the `users` variable above. If the array is populated, I run `createTopics(users)`

```
  [{
    "userUID": "kaLOIkGwrWO4DSFP41OmfozxhsN2",
    "artists": [
      "Adventure Club",
      "LSD",
      "Marshmello"
    ]
  },
  {
    "userUID": "ZvOBNBqxbgRYoibSYEwkL9YKtWG2",
    "artists": [
      "Krewella",
      "Lolo Zouaï",
      "The Chemical Brothers"
    ]
  }]
```

**createTopics()**

This generates the metadata for the push notification for each user. After the message is created, I need to query for all the devices that a specific user owns so that I can push notifications to all of them using Firebase's `multicast()`

```
function createTopics(users) {

    users.forEach((user: any) => {

        const message = {
            notification: {
                title: `my title`,
                body: `my body`
            },
            tokens: null
        }
        // tslint:disable-next-line:no-floating-promises
        findUserDevices(user.userUID, message);
    })
}
```

**findUserDevices()**

This function queries my firestore database for a specific user's device tokens that are needed to send a push notification. If devices exist in our database for that user, we need to push the message to their devices.

```
function findUserDevices(uid: string, message) {
    collectionData(fb.firestore().collection('devices').where('userId', '==', uid)).pipe(
        filter((userDevices) => userDevices && userDevices.length > 0),
        take(1)
    ).subscribe((devices: any) => {
        var userDeviceTokens: string[] = devices.map((device: any) => device.token);
        console.log(userDeviceTokens)
        if (userDeviceTokens !== undefined && userDeviceTokens.length != 0) {
            // tslint:disable-next-line:no-floating-promises
            pushToDevices(userDeviceTokens, message);
        }
    })
}
```

**pushToDevices()**

The following is an async function to push messages to devices...maybe this is where things go awry?? I attach the tokens to the `payload` then I use `sendMulticast()`. On the response of this method, if any tokens fail, I delete them using a `deleteOldToken()` async call.

```
async function pushToDevices(userDeviceTokens, payload) {
    payload['tokens'] = userDeviceTokens;
    await admin.messaging().sendMulticast(payload).then((response) => {
        console.log('Success:', response);
        if (response.failureCount > 0) {
            const failedTokens = [];
            response.responses.forEach((resp, idx) => {
                if (!resp.success) {
                    failedTokens.push(userDeviceTokens[idx]);
                }
            });
            failedTokens.forEach((token) => {
                var tokenInstanceID = token.split(':')[0];
                // tslint:disable-next-line:no-floating-promises
                deleteOldToken(tokenInstanceID);
            })
          }
    })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error:', error)
    });
}
```

**deleteOldToken()**

```
async function deleteOldToken(tokenInstanceID) {
    await fb.firestore().collection('devices').doc(tokenInstanceID).delete().then(() => {
        console.log(`Token ${tokenInstanceID} deleted`)
    })
}
```

**So that's the entire method, here are my logs**

Looking at my console logs, I see a mix of weird activity, with several lines of timeout errors

```
Error: { Error: Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded.
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:152:23
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-timeout',
     message: 'Error while making request: timeout of 10000ms exceeded.' },
  codePrefix: 'app' }
```

Mixed with several lines of connection reset errors:

```
Error: { Error: Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET
    at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:42:28)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:88:28)
    at new FirebaseAppError (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:122:28)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:154:19
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:135:7)
  errorInfo: 
   { code: 'app/network-error',
     message: 'Error while making request: read ECONNRESET. Error code: ECONNRESET' },
  codePrefix: 'app' }
```

While lastly, some work perfectly:

```
Success: { responses: 
   [ { success: true,
       messageId: 'projects/release-hub-f3f5f/messages/1555102845415084' },
     { success: true,
       messageId: 'projects/release-hub-f3f5f/messages/0:1555102845414983%f95cf250f95cf250' } ],
  successCount: 2,
  failureCount: 0 }
```

After contacting some of my users, several received their push notification while many did not. I have a hunch that it has to do with my async calls, but where am I going wrong? Thank you so much for sticking with this question, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue. I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Same issue. No solution anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = new MulticastMessage()
            {
                Tokens = clientTokens,
                Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
                     {
                     {"title", title},
                     {"body", body},
                     },
                Notification = new Notification()
                {
                    Title = title , 
                    Body = body
                }
            };
            var response = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendMulticastAsync(message).Result;
```

this worked for me